# Jquery : Wait for the toastr notification to end then reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, toastr

I am using ajax because of the modal form,
I have a toastr notification to show on the ajax success.

`toastr.success("We will get back to you with response, Thanks !");`

And then :
`window.location.reload();`

How can i make it to end the notification first and then relaod.
I found something but it quickly reloads the page :

```
$.when( toastr.success("We will get back to you with response, Thanks !") ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    window.location.reload();
});
```

Is there any other suitable/Best practice way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The great toastr has already a callback for the end of the hiding animation:

```
toastr.options.timeOut = 1000;
toastr.options.fadeOut = 1000;
toastr.options.onHidden = function(){
  // this will be executed after fadeout, i.e. 2secs after notification has been show
  window.location.reload();
};
```

EDIT:

You can override also just one single toast:

```
toastr.success(
  'Have fun!',
  'Miracle Max Says',
  {
    timeOut: 1000,
    fadeOut: 1000,
    onHidden: function () {
        window.location.reload();
      }
  }
);
```

Comment: So it's static cause we are giving it time. Right ?

Comment: @Gammer: it is already all built in, see my second example - third parameter is for options override. THX